# How to toggle cursor pointer on lightning button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, lightning-button, css3

I'm having a lightning button called "Submit". I have added css property to that button to display it in red color. When I click on that button, I want to change my cursor pointer style to 'not-allowed'. But it didn't work out for me.
Below is the code.

**Component**

```
<lightning:button aura:id = "btnId" class="buttonColor" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.submitClass}">
```

**Controller**

```
submitClass: function(component,event,helper){
    var submitBtn = component.find('btnId');
    $A.util.removeClass(submitBtn,'buttonColor');
    $A.util.addClass(submitBtn,'notAllowedCursor');
}
```

**CSS**

```
.THIS .notAllowedCursor {
  cursor: not-allowed !important;
  background: none !important;
}
.THIS .buttonColor{
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid rgb(196, 13, 13);
  transition: border .15s linear;
  background-color: rgb(196, 13, 13);
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: is button your first element in the component?

Comment: Have you tried changing it to a hover rule instead?  Also, if SF is adding CSS classes, if it also has a "cursor: ... !important" and it's declared later, it would always take precedence: https://css-tricks.com/little-css-stuff-newcomers-get-confused-about/#article-header-id-6  (it's at the bottom, their anchor doesn't work)

Comment: If you're trying to prevent double clicks, you should really disable it instead. Which would be via a Boolean Attribute instead of CSS

Comment: Yes !!! I used disabled option as stackasaur suggested. It worked. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the click method of the button add **disabled="true"** attribute to the button element